# cv::eigen creates transpose eigenvectors w.r.t. the ones from matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, pca, eigenvector

I've written the C++ version of [this](https://github.com/Relja/relja_matlab/blob/master/relja_PCA.m) matlab function for computing PCA (notice that here data are column-wise, as in the original matlab code). If you're interested:

- `U` is the obtained rotation matrix
- `lams` are the eigenvalues of `x`
- `Utmu` is simply `U.t()*mu`
- `x` is the data matrix
- `nPCs` the number of principal components that we want to keep

This is my C++ code (feel free to review it):

```
template <typename T>
void cc::relja_PCA(T &U, T &lams, T &mu, T &Utmu, const T &x, size_t nPCs, const bool substractMean){
    int nPoints = x.cols;
    int nDims = x.rows;

    if(nPCs <= 0)
        nPCs = nDims;

    if(substractMean){
        cv::reduce(x,mu, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
        for(int i=0; i<nPoints; i++){
            x.col(i) = x.col(i) - mu;
        }
    }
    else
        mu = cv::Mat::zeros(1, nDims, x.type());

    bool doDual;
    T X2;
    if(nDims<=nPoints){
        doDual = false;
        cv::mulTransposed(x,X2, false);
    }
    else{
        doDual = true;
        cv::mulTransposed(x, X2, true);
    }

    X2 /= (nPoints-1);

    cv::eigen(X2, lams, U);

    U = U.t();


    //save only the first nPCs elements of L, which is already a vector
    if(nPCs>0 && nPCs<X2.rows){
        lams(cv::Range(0, nPCs), cv::Range(0, lams.cols)).copyTo(lams);
        U(cv::Range(0,U.rows),cv::Range(0,nPCs)).copyTo(U);
    }

    if (doDual){

        cv::Mat1f diag = lams.clone();
        for(int i=0; i<diag.rows; i++)
            diag.at<float>(i,1) = diag.at<float>(i,1) > 1e-9 ? diag.at<float>(i,1) : 1e-9;
        cv::sqrt(diag, diag);
        diag = 1.0f/diag;
        diag = cv::Mat::diag(diag);
        U = x * (U * diag / std::sqrt(nPoints-1)) ;
    }

    Utmu = U.t() * mu;

}
```

The function is called with:

```
//given some nPCs
cv::Mat1f U, lams, mu, Utmu;
cc::relja_PCA(U, lams, mu, Utmu, mat, nPCs);
```

And the projection of a a fature column vector `feat` is done with:

```
feat = U.t()*feat - Utmu; //or equivalently feat = U.t() * (feat- mu);
```

**I have 2 questions:**

1. Why `U` in `cv::eigen(X2, lams, U);` is the transposed version of `[U, L]= eigs(X2, nPCs);` ? As you can see, to guarantee the same results of the original code, I have to `U=U.t();`. Why? I've noticed this while testing the code with a 5x4 toy matrix and nPCs = 3.
2. [We know](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205713/does-the-sign-of-eigenvectors-matter) that the sign of the eigenvectors doesn't matter, but I wonder if this could create any problem in this context. I noticed this some of the columns of `U` had opposite w.r.t. the ones from matlab.

Comment: Regarding the former, since it's really common in linear algebra to have different competing conventions on whether matrices are upper diagonal or lower diagonal or what order the indices are, couldn't this be a simple example of that? Or do you very much expect the convention to be the same?

Comment: Add to the comment above: are you sure OpenCV doesn't do row-major matrices?

Comment: @jwimberley No, the convention doesn't really matter, I was only wondering if there was something wrong with what I was doing (if doing `U=U.t()` was wrong or not

Comment: @CrisLuengo it is, but since modifying the original code so it becomes row-major is kinda dangerous, first I want to test the col-major version, then try to make it row-major

Comment: @justHelloWorld I was saying that because the difference between row-major and column-major is a transpose. I haven't looked over your code, so I don't know if you are taking this into account.

Comment: @CrisLuengo oh so you're saying that the eigenvectors are returned row-wise becuase it's OpenCV style, while they're in Matlab are col-wise because of the same reason, right?

Comment: I'm saying that that is what might be happening. I haven't looked over your code so am not sure. But if you noticed that the matrix was transposed, that could be a thing to investigate.